# How do I give steam permission to write files in a new foder?

Tags: steam

I'm new to linux and I'm trying to install games off of steam and Im trying to change the download folder, but the terminal says it(?) doesn't have write permissions. How fix?

Comment: How did you install Steam?  What file paths is it attempting to use?  (The errors should state it)

Comment: `ls -ld [downloads-path]` will show you the directory's permissions. It needs to be writable by the user that steam runs as. Add the information to your post and we can help with changing permissions if that seems to be necessary.